# S is a possibly infinite set. Prove |S| < |P(S)|

Tags: cardinals

Suppose S is a set. Do not assume that S is finite. How can one prove that |S|<|P(S)|? (P(S) is the power set of S).

Would I say something how the power set is the subset of S so that it contains everything S has but more?

Comment: Where does $T$ appear in the question?

Comment: The classic way to show this is known as [Cantor's diagonalisation argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument#General_sets)

Comment: It waws a 3 part question, this was part 3 (unrelated to the rohter 2 parts).

Comment: I removed the obvious noise of mentioning T, but what remains is still very poorly worded. The power set (of S) is not "the subset of S". Actually writing what things are goes a long way. In any case, no, saying that the power set of S is the collection of all subsets of S does not mean that it contains everything S has. This can be fixed by nothing that for each s in S, the singleton {s} is in P(S). But *it does not matter*. The fact that P(S) contains all singletons (so, in essence, a copy of S) "and more" does not mean that in fact it has larger cardinality.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee You're confusing Cantor's diag argument with Cantor's theorem.

Comment: Yes: "A generalized form of the diagonal argument was used by Cantor to prove Cantor's theorem"

Answer (score 1):

Assume $f:S \rightarrow \mathscr P(S)$ is $1-1$.  Then it can’t be surjective because $\{x \in S~|~x \notin f(x)\}$ can’t be in the range of $f$.  If that set were $f(y)$ for some $y$, then we find $y \in f(y) \iff y \notin f(y)$.